# Winforms : Get visible text extremums in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, c++-cli

I'm trying to limit a treatment to only the current visible text in a richTextBox, but I don't know how to get the first and last visible elements within the richTextBox.

I would like it to work this way :
if (element between first and last visible)
do stuff

I'm coding in C++/CLI, but despaired enough to try and translate any help in any language...

Thanks in advance !

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.getcharindexfromposition(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But I would like to limit the search to only the visible part of the text, not the entire text. Am I missing a detail?

Comment: I think I should be declaring a GetCharIndexFormPosition(Point(0,0)) and a GetCharIndexFormPosition(Point(richTextBox1->ClientSize.Width-1,1)) but I dont know what would come next...